# Move stylesheets into my assets/css directory

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

With gems such as the bootstrap gem and the flexslider gem, you install these css/js frameworks very quickly and easily, but when you want to tweak the css for these frameworks, the stylesheets aren't editable. They're not even in the app. I'm not sure where they are..they're in some weird location, maybe in the Gem, I'm really not sure.

Anyway, is it possible to pull this weird css into my app, so I can edit it? I've used the [Flexslider 2 gem](https://github.com/constantm/Flexslider-2-Rails-Gem) to install flexslider, however, this rule in its css:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

causes a real game-stopping bug in mobile safari. A simply operation to remove the this rule, except for me, the css is stored in this really weird location where I can't edit it! Can I run a rake task or something to pull css into a directory where I can edit it? It's currently being required with sprockets:

```
 *= require flexslider.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions I see:

### Custom CSS

Simply add custom css to do what you want that either overrides or adds to the css you don't want.

Include this line after flexslider's css is included:

```
.flexslider .slides > li { -webkit-backface-visibility: visible; }
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) say that `-webkit-backface-visibility` is initially `visible`

### Download and edit

Just download and add the library to your various assets folders

For flexslider you would pretty much just take everything from [this directory](https://github.com/constantm/Flexslider-2-Rails-Gem/tree/master/vendor/assets) and place it into your own. Then edit it as needed

Comment: With my custom css, can I deactivate the rule? Not override, i don't want to make the element visible, I want to effectively delete the rule?

Comment: I updated my answer a little, but setting it to what it initially is one way to do that, the other is to use option 2 and delete it